# Do hostage situation procedures allow for a heist like this?

Tags: crime

I'd like to split this into two questions, to a degree, although one is entirely dependent on the other. Let's say that a group of criminals are trying to rob a place (either a bank or a jewelry store). Theoretically, this heist would be taking place in 1970's Los Angeles.

The plan revolves around hiding the take in a creative way. The heist crew is split into two groups. The first group will dress themselves normally and enter the bank/store beforehand, acting as regular customers.

Once group one is in place, group two enters, equipped to start a hostage situation. They handle crowd-control and gain access to the take, holding the police at bay with threats against their hostages. Once the take is secured, the leader of group two starts to contact the police, offering to release some hostages. Their demand has to be really, really lenient, something that the police will agree to.

Now, group two will take the hostages of group one into a backroom, away from the normal hostages, where nobody will see them. They gather the take (diamonds seem to be better for this part) and then hide it... in the asses of the group one hostages.

These hostages, with the take hidden inside them, are sent out, where they're taken into police custody, as hostages would normally be. Now comes the crux of the matter.

1. I really don't believe police would be thorough enough with the hostages to either perform an actual cavity or X-ray search. Would the take be discovered while the hostages are in custody?
2. Assuming one could smuggle the take out like this, what item would provide the most money per ass? Money could be rolled up fairly well, but even at that, it'll still take up too much cavity space. Jewelry was my next suggestion, but there'd be a lot of planning involved in trying to identify and exclude the less valuable jewelry.

Comment: Do remember that a hostage is also a witness; the police will want their IDs and contact information before releasing them. They might even have them checked in a hospital just to have additional charges to file against the robbers

Comment: So the robbers, not satisfied with the number of crimes committed, are desirous to add a charge of indecent assault?

Comment: This can work, but can also fail: [Florida man stuffs over $1,000 in rectum](http://pix11.com/2017/08/29/florida-man-stuffs-over-1000-in-rectum-in-attempt-to-hide-it-from-deputies/)

Comment: How does group two make their escape after releasing the hostages of group one?  Group two will have to take something with them or the employees will tell weird stories about incompetent robbers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.  Our [help] states: "Historical events of or historical facts about the real world, except when provided as examples or comparisons in the construction of an imaginary world" are off-topic.  Also, this appears to be a very story-based question, having more to do with plot *(Given situation X, what happens next?)* than it does building a consistent fictional world *(This is what happened, given these laws and culture, is it realistic?)*.  The difference between the two is the first asks us to tell the story for you and the second does not.

Comment: @nzaman Very, very good point. Any number of tests conducted in the hospital could lead to the take being discovered, however, a hospital would be easier to escape from. At the cost of basically shouting "I'm somehow complicit in this", the fake hostages could likely escape with the take.

Comment: This reminds me of a movie from the 80's where bank robbers do this. Except instead of leaving 2 people to risk getting caught they all claim to be hostages and exit the building leaving the real hostages trapped in the vault. I think they used a person on the outside to talk to the negotiator while they did this. They made some kind of distraction and snuck away with the cash taped to their legs and chest, leaving the police confused for a few minutes. It was more of a comedy than a suspense, but it was  planned out and not just running on rule of funny.

Comment: The hostage takers won't get away.  So they are basically volunteering for a prison term - or to be shot by SWAT.  That doesn't seem like something most criminals would do.  Might have to be 'true believers' doing it for a cult or movement.

Answer (score 2):

A guy tried [a variation of that](https://elpais.com/diario/2007/05/22/cvalenciana/1179861494_850215.html)(link in Spanish] in Spain in 2004. A man took several hostages in a bank office and his father came to act as a mediator.

It seems that the kidnapper was a rather convincing guy, because when the father left the office the police discovered that he had €2.400 in his jacket; he claimed that he probably had accidentally swapped his jacket with someone else's, with all the mess at the bank office. Police did not believe him<sup>1</sup>.

The police is likely to at very least pat you down for weapons after you are released; they do not know who you are and they do not take risks. If they feel something strange in the pat down they may research further to determine who are you and if there is enough suspicious, they do a full search of your belongings<sup>2</sup>.

In any case, a hostage situation is a very grave situation, so police will not just tell "Give me a phone number and go home, we will call you. Have a nice day." to the released hostages. At the very least they will want your testimony (which will require identifying you), and will check what your background is (a bank clerk of the office? Ok. The owner of the business a block away? Ok. Some guy from another state with criminal antecedents? "Come this way, we want to have a talk with you.")

---

<sup>1</sup>The last data that I have about this story is that the assaulter was captured when trying to escape and nobody at the bank was harmed; the assaulter did later suicide in jail (he was accused of several other robberies) and his girlfriend and his father were being judged as accomplices in 2007.

<sup>2</sup>Pat downs are supposed to ensure that you do not have weapons or other security risks, so maybe the police won't take away immediately something that feels like a wad of cash.

Answer (score 1):

The weak points in your story are:

1. group two still need to fly away. Now, I am not able to imagine any band to trust half of its component to escape with values in their bodies while the other half is risking its life to escape the heist.
2. the true hostages, once the heist is finished, will tell the police that a group of them was took apart for a while. This will raise suspicion and call for investigation.

Possible mitigation:

Group two is wearing masks and noticeable dresses (i.e. white hoods). Hostages are constantly split into different groups and moved between room. Only once group one is gathered together and "stuffed".

Then (part of) group two swap clothes with real hostages and attempt exiting the place.

Comment: This looks very much like a 1990 movie "[Quick Change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Change)", except for the anal part.

Comment: Your first point is one of my biggest points of consideration. I've been going over many, many possible solutions but the crux of that matter comes down to the question: If group two can escape, why can't they escape with the take? As for your second point, I was going to just stuff all the hostages into one room. They wouldn't know that you'd just decided to release a couple of them, but it'd be easily explained to them in the interview later. It's meant to seem like the released hostages were chosen at random, thereby eliminating the suspicion of separating them.

Comment: @Grizzly, in a comic I read some times ago they hijack an airplane, land it in a forest airport and continuously change room to the hostages. Then the hijackers dress as the hostages and mix with them, until at a certain point "someone" realized the hijackers are gone and all the hostages can leave.